# Spring boot app location inside docker container

Tags: docker, spring-boot, docker-container

Is it possible to see deployed spring-boot jar contents(files) in docker container. If yes, where is the location.

I connect using `docker exec -it container /bin/bash`, could not find files though.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this

https://github.com/havannavar/spring-boot-docker

Once you login to container(`docker exec -it container /bin/bash`), move to folder

> /home/docker/service/

You will see all the files and folders you have pushed to the container